# CIFS share on fstab via krb5

Tags: fstab, cifs, kerberos

I have followed; https://warlord0blog.wordpress.com/2018/03/27/access-dfs-shares-from-linux/

Through this I can mount the cifs share manually, however when I try to mount it in the fstab via kerberos;

```
//windows/share/filepath   /home/Drive cifs user,uid=me,gid=metoo,vers=3.0,rw,sec=krb5  0 0
```

I get

```
➜  ~ sudo mount -a      
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I then changed it to:

```
//windows/share/filepath   /home/Drive cifs _netdev,sec=krb5,noserverino,user,uid=myname,cruid=myname,gid=mygroup,rw  0 0
```

It now fails on boot but works after I run;

```
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: Is this a typo `//windows/sahre/filepath` ( sahre vs share )?

Comment: doesn't really matter, it's not the real filepath :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way that has worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04;

```
sudo vim /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Add wins to the line below;
Change from;

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

To:

```
hosts:          files wins dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

Save & quit

```
sudo vim /etc/request-key.conf
```

Changed the -c (as it's deprecated anyway) option to -t on the cifs.spnego line:

```
create cifs.spnego * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k
```

to;

```
create cifs.spnego * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -t %k
```

Save & quit

Also had to add -t option to cifs.upcall in `/etc/request-key.d/`

```
sudo vim /etc/request-key.d/cifs.spnego.conf
```

Change;

```
create cifs.spnego * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k
```

To;

```
create cifs.spnego * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -t %k
```

Save & quit

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

Append it as per;

```
<server address from above> <mount point locally> cifs _netdev,sec=krb5,noserverino,user,uid=<alias>,cruid=<alias>,gid=domain^users,rw  0 0
```

Save & quit
Mount it with;

```
sudo mount -a
```

You'll now have access, it should also be persistent on reboot